# How to delete "orphaned" Git-Flow feature in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, git-flow

I used to have an open Git-flow feature called `ID-555`. What ended up happening is that local Git branch `feature/ID-555` was deleted and matching remote branch got deleted because feature was no longer needed. However, this feature still shows up in my Team Explorer in ***Current Features*** area as `origin/feature/ID-555`

How can this "orphaned" feature be deleted? I can't finish it because local and remote branches no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

With coworker's help this is how it was resolved: in Visual Studio Team Explorer I navigated to Branches. `origin/feature/ID-555` ***remote*** branch was still listed there even though it didn't exist on server anymore. I deleted it and "orphaned" feature was gone.

I could swear I tried that before and got an error message but now it worked. Go figure...

Comment: Just select "Prune remote branches during fetch" (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191234/how-can-i-refresh-the-list-of-remote-branches-in-my-visual-studio-2017-team-expl ), and all the 'orphaned' Branches get deleted automatically on each fetch.